# SafeMath in ERC20 tokens: throw vs return false

Tags: tokens, security, erc-20, overflow

On the one hand, protecting from over- and underflow [is a must](https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices#integer-overflow-and-underflow), and a widely used [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) library can help with that. SafeMath `throw`s in case of error.

On the other hand, [ERC20](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/20) token functions are expected to return `false` on failure, not `throw`. [This presentation](https://edcon.io/ppt/two/Dmitry%20Khovratovich_Secure%20Token%20Development%20and%20Deployment_EDCON.pdf) advises against throwing in `transfer` and other ERC20 functions that `return bool(success)`.

What is the proper way of protecting against integer errors in tokens while conforming to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually an issue in SafeMath's repo that has been there for a while which references this subject.
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/435

There's also a PR submitted but not yet merged. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/pull/468

I guess you could replace SafeMath for this code if you really need to make the token 100% compliant, or wait a while until they do merge that PR.